# Cache memory simulation in C#

Tags: c#, html, caching, memory, html-table

I am making a simulation of cache memory in C#. The user enters the block size, cache size and the binary number for block placement in cache.

The resulting cache line after block placement would be shown in an html table, and also the block arrangement of whole cache should be displayed. I don't know how to display these cache lines and arrangement of cache according to the selected block size.
Any help?

Comment: You mean you want a visual representation of the bytes in your cache? Well maybe go for a UI similar to a Defrag application, which shows blocks with different color coding.
For that you may not need a table, just subsequent divs using CSS float to have them wrap when a row is full.

Comment: Pablo Romeo yes, you understood the right thing. Please tell me what is this UI similar to Defrag application. And how can i use CSS in c# application

Comment: I just posted a working sample. If that is helpful, feel free to upvote or accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, following what I mentioned in the comment, that maybe a defrag type UI might suit your needs, here's a quick & dirty example of how to do it in html and CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .block { width:20px; height:20px; float:left; border:1px; border-color: black;  border-style:solid; }
            .used { background-color: green }
            .expired { background-color: red }
            .free { background-color: grey }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript">
            var types = ['used', 'expired', 'free'];
            var i = 0;
            while (i < 256) {
                var type = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); //rnd between 0-2
                var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1; //rnd  1-20
                while(size > 0 && i < 256) {
                    document.write('<div class="block ' + types[type] + '"></div>');
                    size = size - 1;
                    i = i + 1;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's I'm just randomly generating 256 blocks, randomly used or free in blocks of up to 20 blocks at a time. Ultimately, it's just a matter of generating a `<div>` with the specific class, and that is all.

It would look like this:
[image]